# Nintex workflow and SharePoint 2019

Tags: sharepoint, nintex-workflow

Good day,

I am getting the error below, please assist, where could the problem be and what should I check?
the error is in Nintex workflow with SharePoint 2019.

**Here is the error**:Failed to invoke web service. Error returned from server: <soap:Fault xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">soap:ServerServer was unable to process request. ---> Attempted to perform an unauthorized

I tried to just cancel the workflow and restarted it because i thought mybe is a user error but still give me the error.

Answer (score 0):

The error message you provided indicates an "Attempted to perform an unauthorized" issue, which suggests that there might be an authentication or permissions problem when the Nintex workflow is trying to invoke a web service within SharePoint 2019. Here are a few steps you can take to troubleshoot and resolve the issue:

1. **Check Workflow Permissions:**
   Ensure that the user account running the workflow has the necessary permissions to access and perform the required actions on the SharePoint site and the external web service. Verify that the account has the appropriate permissions at both the SharePoint and external service ends.
2. **Verify Service Account Permissions:**
   If the web service being called by the workflow requires a service account, make sure that the service account has the necessary permissions to execute the operations.
3. **Review Workflow Configuration:**
   Check the Nintex workflow configuration settings. Ensure that the credentials or authentication method specified in the workflow are correct and up-to-date. If there are any credentials stored, make sure they are not expired or changed.
4. **Check SharePoint Logs:**
   Examine SharePoint logs for more detailed error messages. SharePoint ULS logs (Unified Logging Service) can provide additional information about the error and help pinpoint the root cause.
5. **Review Web Service Security Settings:**
   Verify the security settings on the external web service. Ensure that it allows requests from the SharePoint server and that the authentication method is correctly configured.
6. **Network and Firewall Settings:**
   Confirm that there are no network or firewall issues preventing communication between the SharePoint server and the external web service.
7. **Update Nintex Workflow:**
   Ensure that you are using the latest version of Nintex Workflow for SharePoint 2019. Check for any updates or patches that might address known issues related to web service invocations.
8. **Check User Context:**
   If the workflow is running with elevated permissions, verify that it is not encountering issues when trying to perform actions that require higher privileges.
9. **Test Web Service Outside Workflow:**
   Attempt to invoke the web service outside of the Nintex workflow. This can help determine whether the issue is specific to the workflow or if there's a problem with the web service itself.